# How to scroll the page to the top when i am in missle of page or at end of page using angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my page to scroll top if it is in bottom on click of the button and if it is at the middle then also it must show icon to scroll top.

HTML:

```
<footer>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row containerDiv">
   </div>
 </div>
 <hr />
 <button class="scrollToTop" (click)="goTop()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   </div>
 </div>
 <hr />
</footer>
```

Css:

```
.scrollToTop {
 color: #fafafa;
   float: right;
   margin-right: 2%;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.24);
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   background: #8350ec;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer you are looking for:

**App Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./app.component.css')]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    navIsFixed: boolean;

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

    @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
    onWindowScroll() {
        if (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop > 100) {
            this.navIsFixed = true;
        } else if (this.navIsFixed && window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop < 10) { this.navIsFixed = false; } } scrollToTop() { (function smoothscroll() { var currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; if (currentScroll > 0) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(smoothscroll);
                window.scrollTo(0, currentScroll - (currentScroll / 5));
            }
        })();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!--Scroll to top-->
<div class="scroll-to-top" [ngClass]="{'show-scroll': navIsFixed}">
    <button (click)="scrollToTop()">
        Top
    </button>
</div>
```

**Style:**

```
.scroll-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.show-scroll {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: perfect, Thanks a lot :-)